# When compiling app, it removes References

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, compiler-errors

I have a bizarre problem with a Visual Studio project.  I'm writing a C# application using the .Net 4 framework.  I add a reference to some DLLs (which I believe are compiled in 3.5) and they work until I build the solution.  When this happens, it removes the References in the sense that the compiler cannot see the namespaces within these DLLs.  Any ideas?

The error:

> Error 4   The type or namespace name 'XXX' could not be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: generally with this kind of behaviour you should see warnings in the errors & warnings window - my guess is that a required reference of one of those references is not present in your project.

Comment: are you setting the ecopyLocal = true.. in your project.. ? also keep in mind that 4.0 GAC is separate than 3.5 GAC if you are GAC the .dll's

Comment: @Neil Knight Are you copying the dlls directly into the bin directory?

Comment: @DJKRAZE, @Matthew Cox: Yes, I've got these set `Copy Local` set to `true`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have managed to resolve this problem.  I checked the `Project Properties` and found that it was using `.Net 4 Client Profile` rather than the `.Net 4 Full` framework.  Changing this to the full version has resolved my problem.  I believe the problem is caused due to the lack of the `System.Web` namespace within the `Client Profile`.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you store those dll files in a separate folder in your solution then add references to them from the new said folder. I have had the same exact issue when copying the dlls directly into the bin directory. VS will wipe all those dlls on a clean build so it is not an ideal candidate for permanent storage of said dlls.

Another note:

Despite the options that are supposed to prevent the scenario I suggested, it still seems to happen from my own personal experience and we all know VS isn't bug free! =P

Comment: Can you also try to set the project back to a 3.5 project instead of a 4.0 if you are using .config files.. keep in mind if you are not aware of it already, that 4.0 adds references along with Tokens, this almost sounds like a versioning issue in regards to referencing .dlls from 3.5 vs 4.0 hard to tell also without seeing how you define your namespaces